# Engulfing candles script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I am using this script to identify engulfing candle and have set the alert but the colour on the screen comes but no alerts are triggered: Any thoughts why?

This is the code:-

```
//@version=4
//inspired by HPotter Bullish and Bearish Engulfing scripts
study(title = "Engulfing Candles Detector", overlay = true)

// bullish engulfing
bullishEngulfing = open[1] > close[1] ? close > open ? close >= open[1] ? close[1] >=         open ? close - open > open[1] - close[1] ? color.blue :na :na : na : na : na
barcolor(bullishEngulfing)

// bearish engulfing
bearishEngulfing = close[1] > open[1] ? open > close ? open >= close[1] ? open[1] >=     close ? open - close > close[1] - open[1] ? color.purple :na :na : na : na : na
barcolor(bearishEngulfing)

alertcondition(bullishEngulfing != na, title = "Bullish Engulfing", message =     "[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], Bullish candle engulfing previous candle")
alertcondition(bearishEngulfing != na , title = "Bearish Engulfing", message =     "[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], Bearish candle engulfing previous candle")
```

Answer (score 0):

The engulfing variables you use will be `true` when it is an engulfing candle.

So, use the variable directly in your alert calls.

```
alertcondition(bullishEngulfing, title = "Bullish Engulfing", message =     "[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], Bullish candle engulfing previous candle")
alertcondition(bearishEngulfing, title = "Bearish Engulfing", message =     "[CurrencyPair] [TimeFrame], Bearish candle engulfing previous candle")
```